# What is cheaper: cast to int or Trim the strings in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, string, casting, int

I am reading several files from linux /proc fs and I will have to insert those values in a database. I should be as optimal as possible. So what is cheaper:

i) to cast then to int, while I stored then in memory, for later cast to string again while I build my INSERT statement

ii) or keep them as string, just sanitizing the values (removing ':', spaces, etc...)

iii) What should I take in account to learn to make this decision?

I am already doing a split in the lines, because the order they came is not good enough for me.

Thanks,

Pedro

**Edit - Clarification**

Sorry guys, my scenario is the following: I am measuring cpu, memory, network, disk, etc... every 10 seconds. We are developing our database system, so I cannot count with anything more than just INSERT statements.

I got interested in this optimization because the frequency off parsing data. Its gonna be write once - there will be no updates over the data after it is written.

Comment: Optimal in what sense? Storage-wise or performance-wise?

Comment: Your best bet is to get it working first and then bench marking it to see where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Many database APIs support prepared statements/queries which automatically sanitize values according to the database backend.  Why are you sanitizing manually?

Comment: Premature optimization. Anything you do will be negligible in comparison to the cost of inserting into the DB. Thus do the on that makes the code easier to read (which in my mind is to store integer values in integer objects).

Comment: Thanks guys, I doing as GWW said: gonna finish first, and than benchmark. I just write a clarification for you, I guess my scenario was not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be performing some archiving activity [write-once, read-probably-atmost-once] (storing the DB for a later rare/non-frequent use), if not, you should put the optimization emphasize based on how the data will be read (not written).

If this is the archiving case, maybe inseting BLOBs (binary large objects, [or similar concepts]) into the DB will be more efficient.

**Addition:**
Apparently it will depend on how you will read the data. Are you just listing the data for browse purpose later on, or there will be more complex fetching queries based on the benchmark values.
For example if you are later performing something like: `SELECT * from db.Log WHERE log.time > time1 and Max (Memory) < 5000` then it is best to keep each data in its original format (int in integer, string in String, etc) so that the main data processing is left to DB server.

Comment: "optimization emphasize based on how the data will be read", exactly, this is my thing, and that is my question. Keep it string or cast to int, with the thread off that Loki Astari said: "Thus do the on that makes the code easier to read"

Comment: @PedroDusso well it depends on the type of data usage and fetching (read more at the end of answer above [appended])